# Plotting sized circles with python in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

This is an example of my data:

```
import pandas as pd
mydic = {'user1': {'product': 234, 'device': 567}, 'user1': {'product': 678, 'device': 256},'user2': {'product': 890, 'device': 456},'user2': {'product': 256, 'device': 678},'user3': {'product': 456, 'device': 278}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydic, orient='index', dtype=None)
df.head()
```

[image]

And I can plot scatter or bar charts but for this particular task, I believe, the best way is to show circles for each value sized by the value with annotations for each user. Something like this:

[image]

I'm not even sure it is possible in python. Could anyone suggest something smart?

Comment: If you google for ["draw circle python"](http://www.google.de/search?q=draw+circle+python) you will find how to draw a circle in python. What else can we help you with?

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your specific question (hence the comment), but I do believe bar plots are better than circles. It's easy to see a circle twice as big when in reality it is 4 times as big. You could use seaborn: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/color_palettes.html
Otherwise drawing circles is not very difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not be the most elegant solution, but try:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = len(df)
y = range(n)
scale = 5
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter([[1]] * n, y, s=scale * df['product'])
for i in range(n):
    ax.text(2, y[i], df.index[i])
ax.scatter([[3]] * n, y, s=scale * df['device'])
ax.set_xlim(0, 4)
ax.set_ylim(-1, n);
```

play with styles to get better output (you can remove axis and grid, change size and  colors):

[image: play with numbers to get better ouput]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.